# Style Sheets and hiding .html extension

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, hide

I'm not amazing with web stuff but I have a small portfolio site which I am redesigning. I am looking to hide the `example.com/page.html` and make it website.com/page.

I added the rewrite engine which I found on here for the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  $1.html
```

The only problem is that when I use the `RewriteEngine`, the original path of `/page.html` loads as normal, but when i test it as `/page/` it seems to lose the style sheet, I've tried relinking the style sheet as `.../style.css` instead of just `style.css`, but still all the images and style sheet seem to go missing.

It's probably something pretty damn simple but I need some help here.

Comment: You're catching all extensions, not just `.html`. I should have a better rule around here somewhere.

Comment: i would like to add something in question, what if i am using php files? Can i pass variables to files without .php?

Comment: @user2207792 You need to ask a new, separate question and provide some context of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i understood from your words is that you want to make your url like :
http://www.example.com/page 
ok . if you don't have to use htaccess , you can do this to do what you want .
just change the file name (page.html) to (index.html) . now create a new folder in your root and move the index.html to there !
and if the file , (page.html) is your home page , just change its name into index.html and leave it alone :D !

Comment: I'm wondering if there are any disadvantages do working like this? I never thought about doing that but it seems to work. Obviously not great content/file management though. But results are easier.

Comment: i use this technique for my website ! and there is no advantage or disadvantage !  or even this way is better . because some of servers doesn't allow user to use .htaccess . good luck ...

Answer (score 1):

You probable don't want to rewrite every possible extension, so you might want to try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

What this should do is check to see if a file exists with an `.html` extension. If it does it should transparently append `.html` to the path prior to doing the actual "lookup". So, if you make an HTTP request for

```
http://yourdomain.tld/somepage
```

and your site has an HTML page called `somepage.html`, the actual URL that gets processed will actually be

```
http://yourdomain.tld/somepage.html
```

**EDIT:**

I'm including a Dropbox link for a self-contained example that shows the suggestion above works: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6md9gviv0r2rf9v/xampp.7z

It contains a portable version of Xampp + the source files from this rather nice tutorial: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/04/designing-a-html-5-layout-from-scratch/

Unpack the xampp.7z file somewhere (I recommend the Desktop) and then find and execute the `setup_xampp.bat` file. It will adjust all the internal paths to your local filesystem. Then, run `xampp-control` and start Apache. Once that's running, navigate to `http://localhost:8080/testsite/` - this is the test site. You should be able to bounce back and forth from `http://localhost:8080/testsite/` to `http://localhost:8080/testsite/contact` - both pages have a `.html` extension.

HTH.

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't seem to work. I've tried another users suggestion of mapping to /foldername/index.html so my url would be awstorer.com/portfolio/ instead of awstorer.com/portfolio.html

Is there any disadvantage to working like this? I guess it can be a bit messy but my site doesn't have hundreds of pages so it should be okay?

Comment: @A.W.S It *works*, but I'm not a fan of that process - it doesn't really solve the problem. One thing to try that rules out simple path issues is whether you can make a direct request for the CSS file/image; for instance, does http://yourdomain.tld/path/to/yourcssfile.css return the contents of your CSS file?

Comment: http://awstorer.com/style.css is my css file. I guess I never use live links because I'm usually building a site locally; not live. What's the complete code I should use in .htaccess? Just the Request and Rewrite you posted?

Comment: You would also need to leave in `RewriteEngine On`, but yeah, that *should* be all you need. In all fairness, though, I work mostly with IIS and ASP.NET MVC these days, so my `mod_rewrite` is a little rusty...

Comment: @A.W.S I'm building a sample site in XAMPP portable. I'll let you know when I have a better answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I'll work on it. Trying to make the insides pretty as well as the outsides.

Comment: @A.W.S We need to avoid chatting, but see my edit above. The sample code should help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't necessarily have to do with the RewriteRules, but with paths. You should, in general, always use absolute paths to images and assets. So instead of loading `style.css` or `../style.css`, load `/style.css` or `/static/styles/style.css`. Otherwise the browser tries to resolve relative to the *page location*, and `/page` is considered to be in the root folder while `/page/` is thought to be its own folder.

Iow, if you load `style.css` from your page:

- From `/page` it will load `/style.css`
- From `/page/` it will load `/page/style.css`

Always use absolute paths, save yourself the pain and frustration.

Apart from that, ensure the images and assets are also not rewritten into `.html` extensions as mentioned in the other answers.