# How to hide file extension(html)?

Tags: html, .htaccess

i had tried to hide the file extension using htaccess but failed.
this is the code on my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\ (INSERT FILE EXTENSION) -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 (INSERT FILE EXTENSION)
```

and in my html file the code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is profile</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

when i accessing the webpage without the extension i got this error
[image: error from browser]

[image: folder]

Comment: https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430500/style-sheets-and-hiding-html-extension/16430743#16430743